# Is there a relation between звонила and телефоне?

Tags: этимология

*-вон-* in *звонила* sounds a lot like *-фон-* in *телефоне*, so I wondering if the former comes from the latter.

The reason I don't think the relation (if it exists) can't be the other way around is that it is pretty clear that *телефоне*, like the italian *telefono*, comes from greek words *τῆλε* and *φωνή*, where the latter means *sound*.

On the other hand, the action of calling somebody has to do with sound, so I suspect that *-вон-* might be an altered *-фон-*.

Comment: звон - от звук, звенеть, звяк, ἦχος - something hearing by the ear, a sound. φωνή - close to singing, barking, pronounced by the voice, to sound, a vowel sound, a speech, phonetics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using wiktionary etymology:

телефон - ultimately from Ancient Greek τῆλε (têle, “afar”) + φωνή (phōnḗ, “voice, sound”).  From Proto-Hellenic *pʰōnā́, from Proto-Indo-European *bʰoh₂-néh₂, from *bʰeh₂- (“to speak”) (whence φημί (phēmí, “to say, speak”)).

звонила - From звон. Pokorny reconstructs the root as Proto-Indo-European *ǵʰwon- (whence Albanian zë), however Derksen holds that the root *swenh₂- (whence Latin sonus) must be considered a serious alternative.

So at the level of Proto-Indo-European they are supposedly different.  But going back further in time there could still be a connection.